# Best way to Insert Millions records in Azure SQL on daily basis?

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-sql-database

I am maintaining millions of records in Sql Server 2008 R2 and now i am intended to migrate these on SQL Azure.

In existing system with **SQL Server 2008 R2**, few SSIS packages and Stored Procedures are firstly truncate the existing records and then perform Insert operation on the table which holds **approx 26 Million records** in 30 mins. on **Daily basis** (as system demands).

When i migrate these on SQL Azure, i am unable to perform these operations in a **faster** way as i did in SQL 2008. Sometimes i got Request timeout error.

While searching for faster way, many of them suggest for **Batch process or BCP**. But Batch processing is NOT suitable in my case because it takes much time to insert those records. I required some faster and efficient way on SQL Azure.

Hoping for some good suggestions.

Thanks in advance :)
Ashish Narnoli

Comment: Can you provide the table definition of the target table, including indexes and foreign keys?  What is the structure of the package - are you using a dataflow, linkedserver in a proc?  If a dataflow, is it doing anything more than just reading the source records and inserting them?

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely use the new V12 version of Azure SQL DB because:

1. Better write performance
2. more log bandwidth
3. you can use heaps to get the data into SQL DB and then process it
4. perhaps you can use table partitioning to manage the table in chunks for insert/deletes and index management

Comment: Do you have any sources to corroborate the "better write performance" Is that in all cases or only in some specialised workloads?